# NSNetServiceBrowser did NOT find published service

Tags: objective-c

On an iPhone (the server), I've tried to publish a service and my code ran into the `NSNetService` object's delegate method:

```
-(void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender
```

So I believe that my service `@"_chatty._tcp."` has published successfully. Then on another iPhone (the client), I use `NSNetServiceBrowser` to find my service, but it did NOT run into the delegate method:

```
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing
```

I found some questions related to my case on this site, most of the answer remind to check the delegate object whether is out of scope or not. I'm sure my delegate work well because it ran into another delegate method like:

```
-(void)netServiceBrowserWillSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser
```

Can anybody help me find out the reason?

Here are some parts of my code:

I init the service like that:

```
#define MY_PROTOCOL @"_chatty._tcp."

self.myService = [[NSNetService alloc]
                   initWithDomain:@"" type:MY_PROTOCOL
                   name:@"thaith" port:self.port];
```

The port is initialized with a given listeningSocket in the Browser class:

```
NSNetServiceBrowser* finder = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];

//I also retain the finder.
finder.delegate = self;

[finder searchForServicesOfType:MY_PROTOCOL inDomain:@""];
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem...did you find out the solution for it??

Answer (score 10):

After having come across the same problem and giving up for a month. I've just come back to it and solved it:

Even though [the sample code in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-CJBDDCAB) seems to imply otherwise, **don't use a local variable** for the NSNetServiceBrowser.  As soon as it goes out of scope it gets garbage collected.  Make `finder` an instance variable or property so its sticks around.  I didn't spot this straight away as the `netServiceBrowserWillSearch:` delegate was getting called so I assumed everything was ok...

Comment: There is a good code sample here: https://github.com/thesecretlab/LearningCocoa3rdEd/blob/ecc8d34b151c116c4fc3b3296b3c0df1e57171d5/iTunesDetector/iTunesDetector/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Why didn't I read this an hour ago? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Solutions**

> 1. Check both WiFi identifiers are same
> 2. Check both are in same WiFi network
> 3. Check the NSNetServiceBrowser delegate assigned as same class

At last download sample [**Apple.Developer Witap Application**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) , install in two devices , test and confirm it working.

Comment: I've check with Witap example, and it seems to do nothing, like my app. I also check wifi address and I configure manually to make them the same network, but still not work, my app and witap app.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading bonjour browser, I suggest using the terminal command:

```
dns-sd -B _chatty._tcp local.
```

For me, it shows that the server side is working fine.
Currently, I can find the service when my application starts, my only issue is that once I stop the server, I get the "removed" event but running it again, I cant discover it anymore. I know the problem is on my client side, thanks to dns-sd - B

Answer (score 0):

I would narrow the scope and try to find the problem place. First, find out whether the service is published correctly. Use Bonjour Browser application (you can find it in the Internet) on a computer within the same local network where you publish the service. I hope you publish and browse in the same local net. If the Bonjour Browser can see your service then you know it is published correctly. Then work on the browser side to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes, I did a breakpoint on the delegate method         -(void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender                      and it run into it, so I think my service public successfully. It just not run into delegate didFIndService